# Starting ffmpeg.exe asynchronously?

Tags: c, asynchronous, process, ffmpeg

Is it possible to start `FFmpeg` from within a C program and then not wait till the process terminates, but move on to the next line of code. At present, I'm using

```
int startFFmpeg()
{
    char cmd[100] = "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\\video.mpg -r 10 D:\\frames\\%d.jpg";
    int ff = system(cmd);
    return ff;
}

int main()
{
   int ff = startFFmpeg(); // great! ffmpeg has started, now immediately move to next part of code
   if(ff)
   {
       // execute code in this block simultaneously?
       // i.e. do not wait till ffmpeg closes
   }
   else
   {
      // error handling
   }

  return 0;
}
```

#### Some Metadata

OS : **Windows 7**
Language: **C**
IDE : **Dev C++**

### UPDATE

I tried using `CreateProcess()`. The problem now is that `ffmpeg.exe` is listed in the taskbar, but the frames are not getting extracted.

```
char cmd[100] = "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\\video.mpg -r 10 D:\\frames\\%d.jpg";
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
CreateProcess(cmd, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

Comment: Try `CreateProcess` instead ?

Comment: Isn't that a C++ function?

Comment: It's a win32 function.

Comment: Oh...how silly of me..excuse my noobness as I'm a novice in C...So I can use that inside C?

Comment: Sure you can. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Alirght. I've had partial luck now. I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution. I was using wrong argument for `CreateProcees()`. The following code solved it.

```
CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```